# Flex object not typed correctly

Tags: php, apache-flex, amfphp

I'm struggling to get a flex class instance back to Amfphp (v2.2)

Simplified code in Flex:

```
    [RemoteClass(alias="Project")]
    public class Project
    {
        public function Project()
        {
        }
    }
```

Code in php:

```
    class Project {
        var $_explicitType = "Project";

        public function foo()
        {
            return "bar";
        }
    }
```

At a point, I send this code to the server:

`myRemoteObjectService.testMethod(myProjectInstance);`

Which is handled in php like this:

```
    public function testMethod($projectInstance)
    {
        return $projectInstance->foo;
    }
```

This should return 'bar' to my Flex application but instead, I get

faultCode:Channel.Call.Failed faultString:'error' faultDetail:'NetConnection.Call.Failed: HTTP: Status 500'

What DOES work is:

```
    public function testMethod()
    {
        $project = new Project();
        return $project->foo;
    }
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

Dany

Comment: When the object comes back to php:
- All properties of $projectInstance are preserved
- $projectInstance->_explicitType returns 'Project'
- $classMethods = get_class_methods($projectInstance); return empty Array!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:
The standard location for vo objects is /Services/Vo/
In my case, my vo objects where in /dto/
When I put all my vo objects into /Services/Vo/, everything worked as expected.

BUT

I tried setting /dto/ in config using:

`$this->voFolders = array(AMFPHP_ROOTPATH . 'dto/');`

And that didn't work.
So:

- I'm glad to have solved the question
- Is this a bug in the Amfphp
  config?

Answer (score 0):

Vo conversion is handled by the Vo converter plugin. IT's described here http://www.silexlabs.org/amfphp/documentation/plugins/plugins-distributed-with-amfphp/vo-converter/
Try something like this in your config

```
$this->pluginsConfig["AmfphpCustomClassConverter"] = array(“customClassFolderPaths” => array(AMFPHP_ROOTPATH . “MyVoFolder”));
```